# Large deviations theory and extreme value theory

Tags: risk-management, probability, distribution, value-at-risk, finance-mathematics

I'll enter into details of both, sooner or later, but for the moment I'm concerned about the differences (and relationships, if any) between these two theories. Can someone give me a brief, but still a little technical, explanation of the divergences (common points) of these theories? 
Thank you all.

Comment: Extreme Value theory is concerned with the prob. dist. of the maximum (or minimum) of several random variables. For example the rainfall in centimeters is measured every day at a certain location; what can we say about the maximum yearly rainfall (that is the max of the 365 daily values for one calendar year)?

Large deviations theory, I am less familiar with, is concerned with the behavior of their tails of the distribution of a r.v. as a parameter N becomes large. The Central Limit theorem tells you what happens to the mean, the LD Theory tells you about the tails.

Comment: Thank you. Well, suppose you want to the estimate the Value at Risk of one stock (as a starting point; I know that they are used to this purpose, too): how do they differ in the estimation? Why and when is better one or the other?

Comment: I considered the application of EVT to the calculation of VaR a few years ago. But I concluded from a paper by Diebold that EVT is not really necessary for the calculation of 5% or 1% VaR as these are not extreme enough; it might help in estimating the 0.1% events if you are interested in those. Also EVT assumes that variables are iid, which is not the case for stock returns due to GARCH effects. http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper21/dss-f.pdf So I have never used EVT methods for VaR.

Comment: @noob2 It seems interesting. However, in this paper of McNeil & Frey (2000) [link](http://www.financerisks.com/filedati/WP/EVT/olddynamic.pdf) a conditional approach to the EVT is (succesfully, it seems) applied to the VaR and CVaR estimation. What do you think about it?

Comment: McNeil & Frey paper is interesting.

Comment: Whoever concluded you should not use EVT to estimate CVAR is making a big fundamental mistake ordinary CVAR does not have the same assurance as EVT estimated CVAR, in any way, shape, or form! I have previously used Garch with estimating EVT CVAR, but I think using spectral density methods, would afford a better risk measure and a greater level of Risk assurance.

Comment: Ordinary CVAR assumes normality or stable conditions, where as EVT does not, and Benoit Mandelbrot spent his life proving this: that markets go in and out of periods of chaos, where all the usual bets are off, it seems a ludicrous argument to forget an ounce of extreme protection to prevent a pound of extreme loss.

Comment: McNeil and Fry's paper is a meta paper taking research, from Coles who Implemented EVT in S pre R language days, it was implement in R and further deloped by the RMetrics Econophysics team, who gathered together all the extant methods in R under fExtremes package. R Tsay, was influential , so is Bernard Pfaff, and there is a whole series of journal articles gathered together form the top academics from all over the world researching and working in the field, called Extreme Events in Finance, published by Wiley with Francois Longin as editor.

Comment: Please crawl out of the google bubble,Get with the strength and crawl out from under google's toxic search rankings. DuckDuckgo, yippy.com, swisscows, lastpage, and even googlescholar is preferable. Google is pay to play and extreme dumbing down, like faeces-book and I'm-a-twitter, sheer waste of time nonsense. Seek and ye shall find!

Comment: Real quants have been using Extreme value theory in S and R for over 30 years, it is not new or even remotely a fringe or marginal theory, it is mainstream and grist to the mill of actuaries everyday finance estimations.

Comment: There is a book by French Professor Arthur Charpentier called Acturlal and Financial methods in R which discusses EVT at length published by CRC Chapman Hall publishers.