# Large deviations theory in finance

Tags: statistics, finance-mathematics, probability, distribution, cvar

In probability theory, the **theory of large deviations** concerns the asymptotic behavior of remote tails of sequences of probability distributions.

A [related post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22706/large-deviations-theory-and-extreme-value-theory) says:

> Large deviations theory is concerned with the behavior of the tails of the distribution of a r.v. as a parameter N becomes large. The Central Limit theorem tells you what happens to the mean, the LD Theory tells you about the tails.

Not sure what $N$ refers to that becomes large, but what are some common and ***practical* applications** of large deviations theory in finance? (Practical as in *usable* within a well-known financial model, as opposed to theoretical, pointless meanderings about stochastic process behaviors.)

Or better, what is the **most popular measure** or metric put out by large deviations theory (in the same way that the measure called expected shortfall (CVaR) was borne from extreme value theory)?

Please no links to papers from google search unless you plan to
explain what those papers actually contain.

Comment: I don't know for sure but it's relation to crashes come to mind. I would look at material of Nassim Taleb or Didier Sornette..

Comment: I think large deviations theory feature most prominently in risk management, and perhaps not as much directly to finance as to say, actuarial maths, dealing with insurance claims for very rare events. One approach to model tail risk for heavy tailed distribution you can fit a Generalized Pareto Distribution to just the tail part of the EDF and in that way get more realistic probability measures for outcomes more extreme than those previously observed (e.g. 99.9% VaR of 300 sample occurrences). You could look up Peaks Over Threshold method

Comment: Peaks over threshold comes from the VaR-extreme value theory pundits, which are not in the same niche as large deviations theory

Comment: I don't think large deviations theory has seen enough development yet to be of use in finance. There are some advances in large deviations for martingales that might be of interest (e.g. over brownian filtration), but that's about it.

Comment: Just a comment: let us not mix Large Deviation Theory (LDT) with Extreme Value Theory (EVT), see eg. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22706/large-deviations-theory-and-extreme-value-theory.

Comment: I don't think you are going to arrive where you think you are going to arrive.  With large deviation theory you are looking at *sequences* of distributions.  In effect, you are non-stationary, unless there is a parameterized function that links them.  In extreme value theory, you are looking for the expected maximum or minimum value of a distribution, although there is no reason it couldn't be applied to a sequence of distributions.  I have not seen any metrics used with large deviations theory in what little attention I have paid to it.

Comment: Why not mention EVT, as large deviations are not necessary to estimate, they are self evident from historic data, re: finance, we are not discussing the natural sciences here but social sciences not the same thing. for my discussion on extreme tail risk and Talebs black swans see          https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55263/how-do-traders-hedge-against-tail-side-risk-in-practice/55273#55273

Comment: Extreme changepoint detection theory is far more prevalent in finance than large deviations theory, in fact, I have never seen a quant, not an actuary use it. Regarding extreme changepoint detection, see the following topics; Runs tests, control theory and the Shiryaev Roberts statistic. Books on Crashes by Didier Sornette, William Ziemba, forget Taleb populist post ergo hoc clairvoyant, large on commentary, low on real practical real life advice re: risk management.

Comment: For a start any paper that appeals to gaussian or normal curves should be taken with a grain of salt, actually Taleb and Dermans non parametric derivation of black scholes not utilising any gaussian theory rescues the BSM model from the waste basket of history as another economic piece of rational man neo classical romantic economic theory nonsense. The Derman Taleb theory relies on the earlier Thorp Kousseff model, and relies on no arbitrage and is consitent with the volatility smile, which should not exist in a gaussian BSM world.

Comment: Virtually no shares are Gaussian distributed , truly , and most are not even approximate log-normal. They approach at best a fat tailed or highly peaked T-distribution approximation, they are uncertain, so as a general rule use chebyshev's theorem when the Hurst coefficient is .5 or below, chebyshev states for an unknown distribution estimate 2 st devs as1-( 1/2^2) < ~ Z 2 st.dvs. or about 75% probability NOT 95% probability and 3 st.dv. has 89% probability NOT 99% etc. and 1 st dev has 50% probability no greater than chance, you really need heavy odds stacked in your favour.

Comment: Most mean variance portfolio models are gaussian and time static, making them practically useless in reality also. Lovely maths, bad results. You should use a robust mean C.V.A.R. model(mini-max in game theory) or stochastic optimization multi-stage model, two of the best I have utilized. There is a plethora of others yet for its mathematical elegance and simplicity in teaching finance, it is used to teach redundant finance methods, such as this and the BSM option model, and GARCH, which has little use. It is the variance over time that gives the sausage its sizzle, not the other way around.